# Taking values from a SELECT with INNER JOIN statement and doing an UPDATE with those values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT dbo.ProductType.Id
FROM dbo.ProductType 
INNER JOIN dbo.RawProduct ON dbo.ProductType.SourceId = dbo.RawProduct.ProductTypeId
```

Looking to take this `SELECT` and use it to do an update on a separate table called `dbo.Product` and update the column `ProductTypeID`

Comment: You can use [MERGE Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) from SQL Server 2008. And please read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the relationship between Product and ProductType tables please

Comment: Id in ProductType Table is associated with ProductId in Product table

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)